# Crash when trying to play AVC High Profile video on Android 4.2 (Nexus 7)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a TS with AVC High Profile video and it does not play at all on on Android 4.2.
The short stream sample is available at: [vid-avc-hp_aud-mp3.ts](http://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=550810001000&name=vid-avc-hp_aud-mp3.ts&token=ctIyTaTfk_93F-LKTPYmU6oVy0A%3A1369120112118)

The stream "vid-avc-hp_aud-mp3.ts" could be played using `MediaPlayer` on such devices:
1. Asus Transformer TF201 (with Android 4.1.1)
2. Acer Iconia Tab A510 (with Android 4.1.2)

When I try to play the stream on Nexus 7 (with Android 4.2.2) using `MediaPlayer` it does not play at all. There here is only a crash in logcat:

```
05-08 14:25:31.275: A/avc_utils(15626): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/avc_utils.cpp:63 CHECK_EQ( br.getBits(1),0u) failed: 1 vs. 0
05-08 14:25:31.275: A/libc(15626): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 15666 (TimedEventQueue)
```

The full logcat from Nexus 7 is available at: [logcat_crash](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=55081&aid=550810000000&name=4.2+Player+error.txt&token=Rjc7bEsyUYPh_gs2MXvA6HUJbak%3A1369120112118)

The crash is from `media/libstagefright/avc_utils.cpp` at the following function of Android sources:

```
// Determine video dimensions from the sequence parameterset.
void FindAVCDimensions(
        const sp<ABuffer> &seqParamSet, int32_t *width, int32_t *height) {
    ABitReader br(seqParamSet->data() + 1, seqParamSet->size() - 1);

    unsigned profile_idc = br.getBits(8);
    br.skipBits(16);
    parseUE(&br);  // seq_parameter_set_id

    unsigned chroma_format_idc = 1;  // 4:2:0 chroma format

    if (profile_idc == 100 || profile_idc == 110
            || profile_idc == 122 || profile_idc == 244
            || profile_idc == 44 || profile_idc == 83 || profile_idc == 86) {
        chroma_format_idc = parseUE(&br);
        if (chroma_format_idc == 3) {
            br.skipBits(1);  // residual_colour_transform_flag
        }
        parseUE(&br);  // bit_depth_luma_minus8
        parseUE(&br);  // bit_depth_chroma_minus8
        br.skipBits(1);  // qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag
        CHECK_EQ(br.getBits(1), 0u);  // seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag   //<<-- the crash is here
    }
    (...)
```

I checked that the problem is generally with playback of any AVC HighProfile transport streams since android 4.2

Deeper analysis of the stream "vid-avc-hp_aud-mp3.ts" showed that the issue is with the parser of the "Sequence parameter set RBSP" for AVC High Profile. The "Sequence parameter set RBSP" for High Profile contains some additional fields. The problem is with "seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag" and following scaling matrix structure. If "seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag" is set to 1 - next bytes contain scaling coefficients.

**I have following questions:**
1. How to play TS stream with AVC High Profile video on Android?
   *note: Due to stream server performance limitations it is not possible to transcode the stream to any lower profile.*
2. Why Android can't parse this structure, which is correct according to the norm: *ISO/IEC 14496-10*?

Comment: I would like to add a general question for Android dev team: why does CHECK_EQ causes an assert and subsequent SIGSEGV? Shouldn't the CHECK_* macros be defined to do nothing in production code?